# Ошибка при публикации SQL CRL из Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql

Делаю сборку CRL для SQL. Необходимо чтобы она была в режиме UNSAFE. При публикации выдает ошибку.

```
Выполняется создание [Database1]...
(47,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Сообщение 10327, уровень 14, состояние 1, строка 1 CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'Database1' failed because assembly 'Database1' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE.  The assembly is authorized when either of the following is true: the database owner (DBO) has UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission and the database has the TRUSTWORTHY database property on; or the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.
(47,0): SQL72045: Ошибка выполнения скрипта. Выполненный скрипт:
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Database1]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 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
При выполнении пакета произошла ошибка.
```

При этом права UNSAFE у пользователя БД есть, `Trustworthy = true`. Что еще может быть не понятно. Пробовал подписывать сборку сертификатом. Но каменный цветок не вышел. Что можно еще попробовать? Перерыл гугл, и ничего не нашел(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2011/10/28/deploying-sql-clr-assembly-using-asymmetric-key/ -

Сделал как описано тут - после этого все заработало. Думаю описывать это решение тут не нужно.